# CSS: position changing on changin resolution

Tags: css, html

I am making a header for my website. I have a search box in the header and the search results should appear right below it. I adjusted the position of the search results div but when i changed the resolution of the screen the div moved away.
I have the following code in html:

```
<div id = "header">
    <div id = "header_wrapper">
        <div id = "search_results">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0px;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #f1f1f1;   
    height:100px;
}
#header_wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid #f1f1f1;
    height:100px;
}
#search_results{
    position:absolute;
    left:30%;
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #f1f1f1;
    top:100px;
}
```

How can I adjust the div so that it does not change its relative position with it's parent div on changing the screen resolution.Please help

Comment: can you a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Replace your css with this, i hope it will work as you want.

```
 *{
    margin:0px;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
#header_wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}
#search_results{
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    top:80px;
}
```